# plot.new has not been called yet

Tags: r, plot

Why does this happen?

```
plot(x,y)
yx.lm <- lm(y ~ x)
lines(x, predict(yx.lm), col="red")
```

> Error in `plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...)` : 
>         `plot.new` has not been called yet

Comment: Works here when applied to two short vectors. Please show us `str(x)` and `str(y)`.

Comment: How do you expect us to comment with specifics? We don't have `x`, `y`, nor the code used to fit the linear model. Please help us to help you.

Answer (score 46):

Some action, very possibly not represented in the visible code, has closed the interactive screen device.
It could be done either by a "click" on a close-button, or it could also be done by an extra dev.off() when plotting to a file-graphics device. (The second possibility might happen if you paste in a multi-line plotting command that has a `dev.off()` at the end of it, but had errored out at the opening of the external device. So the dangling `dev.off()` on a separate line accidentally closes the interactive device).

Some (most?) R implementations will start up a screen graphics device open automatically, but if you close it down, you then need to re-initialize it.
On Windows that might be `window()`; on a Mac, `quartz()`; and on a Linux box, `x11()`. You also may need to issue a `plot.new()` command. I just follow orders. When I get that error I issue `plot.new()` and if I don't see a plot window, I issue `quartz()` as well. I then start over from the beginning with a new `plot(., ., ...)` command and any further additions to that plot screen image.

Comment: This answer is similar to  the "if in doubt, reformat your hard drive" advice.  There's no need to add unwanted plot.new() calls.  The OP (obviously) left out  his lm() call, and most likely some other call that closed is plot window.  plot.new() will not "re-attach" to the existing plot of x vs y, so his lines() call wouldn't be written to that plot.

Comment: If it is at worst harmless, then it is not similar to your example nor even similar to rm(list=ls()).

Comment: It is not always harmless.  And as I pointed out, plot(x,y);plot.new();lines(...) will *not* do what the OP wanted

Comment: I suppose. I didn't imagine that it would have been issued between the `plot` and the `lines` commands. I was assuming it would be issued before the plot call. As I said ... after the interactive graphics device has been re-initialized, I then redo the plotting operation from the beginning.

Comment: on linux, I used plot.new().

Answer (score 26):

In my case, I was trying to call `plot(x, y)` and `lines(x, predict(yx.lm), col="red")` in two separate chunks in Rmarkdown file. It worked without problems when running chunk by chunk, but the corresponding document wouldn't knit. After I moved all plotting calls within one chunk, problem was resolved.

Comment: You also get the error if you try to run the lines separately within the same chunk, rather than executing the whole thing. I guess it calls `dev.off()` somewhere under the hood?

Answer (score 6):

As a newbie, I faced the same 'problem'.

In newbie terms : 
when you call `plot()`, the graph window gets the focus and you cannot enter further commands into R. That is when you conclude that you must close the graph window to return to R.
However, some commands, like `identify()`, act on open/active graph windows.
When `identify()` cannot find an open/active graph window, it gives this error message.

However, you can simply click on the R window *without closing the graph window*. Then you can type more commands at the R prompt, like `identify()` etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem... my problem was that I was closing my quartz window after plot(x,y). Once I kept it open, the lines that previously resulted in errors just added things to my plot (like they were supposed to). Hopefully this might help some people who arrive at this page.

Answer (score 2):

If someone is using `print` function (for example, with mtext), then firstly depict a null plot:

```
plot(0,type='n',axes=FALSE,ann=FALSE)
```

and then print with `newpage = F`

```
print(data, newpage = F)
```

Answer (score 2):

plot.new() error occurs when only part of the function is ran.

Please find the attachment for an example to correct error
With error....When abline is ran without plot() above
[image]
Error-free ...When both plot and abline ran together
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem in an RMarkdown, and putting the offending line on the previous line of code helped.

#### Minimal Reproducible Example

This will error if run line by line in an Rmd:

```r
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
           matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y")
(cl <- kmeans(x, 2))
plot(x, col = cl$cluster)
points(cl$centers, col = 1:2, pch = 8, cex = 2)
```

but this works:

```r
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
           matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y")
(cl <- kmeans(x, 2))
plot(x, col = cl$cluster); points(cl$centers, col = 1:2, pch = 8, cex = 2)
```

The only change is that the offending line (the last one) is placed after the last succeeding line (placing a `;` in between). You can do it for as many offending lines as desired.