# how to specify x-axis value for date in R

Tags: r

I want to figure out when exactly the number of calls sharply increased.

Here is my original code:

```
plot(breaks, cumfreq0, main="Cumulative percentage of calls happened in NOV.7th", xlab="time", ylab = "cumulative percentage of calls", sub = "(each dot represents a single period of time on Nov.7th)")
```

[image: plot]

but I don't think the time scale on the x-axis is specific enough.
*How can I change it?*

I tried some times as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775692/how-to-specify-the-actual-x-axis-values-to-plot-as-x-axis-ticks-in-r) but it seems that codes does fit time object.

[image]
Many many thanks for any help

Comment: Please take the time to provide context, code and explanations. Don't put image of your code/erros but copy them in your post.

Comment: Well I think it doesn't matter but it's alright if I need to explain the context. I aim to display the percentage of calls that accumulate with time going on on Nov.7th. I'm trying to figure out when the calls among customers sharply increase within the specific period of time.

Comment: here is all my chunk before the final plot code I've shown

Comment: library(lubridate)
timestamp<-ymd_hms(as.character(latencies$Timestamp))
timestamp<-timestamp[order(timestamp)]
timestamp<-timestamp[timestamp>ymd_hms("2018-11-07 00:00:00")]
cum <- c(0, cumsum(table(timestamp))) 
breaks<-ymd_hms(seq(ymd_hms("2018-11-07 06:52:24"),ymd_hms( "2018-11-07 22:26:04"), by=1000))
timestamp.cut = cut(timestamp,breaks, right=FALSE) 
timestamp.freq = table(timestamp.cut) 
cumfreq0 = c(0, cumsum(timestamp.freq))/33.82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below, i just replicated your example with dummy data

```
> df
# A tibble: 55 x 2
   datetime             Freq
   <dttm>              <int>
 1 2018-11-01 12:41:57   215
 2 2018-11-01 12:41:58   163
 3 2018-11-01 12:47:06   225
 4 2018-11-01 12:51:00    69
 5 2018-11-01 12:57:37   203
 6 2018-11-01 12:57:38   248
 7 2018-11-01 12:57:38    58
 8 2018-11-01 13:29:15   179
 9 2018-11-01 13:37:45   233
10 2018-11-01 14:24:43   150
# ... with 45 more rows
```

And the code to kind of plot you are expecting with x-axis as timestamp and you can give whichever format you want

```
plot(df$datetime,df$Freq,xaxt="n")
axis.POSIXct(1, at=df$datetime, labels=format(df$datetime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

[image: Output image with x-axis as timestamp]

Comment: Yes I tried                                                                                                      plot(breaks,cumfreq0,main="Cumulative percentage of calls happened in NOV.7th",xlab="time",ylab = "cumulative percentage of calls",sub = "(each dot represents a single period of time on Nov.7th)",xaxt="n")
axis.POSIXct(1, at=breaks, labels=format(breaks, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))                                                                                                    but R still shows me this:Error in axis(side, at = z, labels = labels, ...) : plot.new has not been called yet

Comment: And please clear the plot window once and start execution from `plot()` line by line

Comment: Yes, I think so. here is my check> breaks %>% class()
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

Comment: yes, I close it  and then open it again, R shows me the same result.

Comment: Please go through this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154133/plot-new-has-not-been-called-yet