# abline only using two coefficients

Tags: r, dataframe

Data Set

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k_fVtpMKf9_4rUsKXkNQ9-it7hHzKs7U/view?usp=sharing

```
PHONE <- read.csv(file = "~/Desktop/311NY.csv")

Data311 = PHONE$count
Data311 = PHONE[,2]

Data311

plot(Data311, type="o", col="orange", xlab="Date", ylab="Calls", main="Time Series Analysis of 311 Calls")

abline(lm(Calls~Date, data=PHONE), col="black" )
```

> Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) :
>
> plot.new has not been called yet
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In abline(lm(Calls ~ Date, data = PHONE), col = "black") :
>
> only using the first two of 365 regression coefficients

I keep receiving this error message proceeded by an empty graph. 
I've already tried the following to trouble shoot.

```
plot(Calls ~ Date, data =PHONE)
model <- lm(Calls ~ as.numeric(as.character(Date)), data=PHONE)
```

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
>
> 0 (non-NA) cases
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In eval(predvars, data, env) : NAs introduced by coercion

Answer (score 1):

Quite a lot of separate problems here.

First, `Data311 <- PHONE$count` won't work, because `PHONE` has no column named `count`. You want `PHONE$Calls`, if you don't want to use `PHONE[, 2]`.

Second, `plot.new has not been called yet` means that your plot did not work for some reason. It's not clear why from the code that you have posted, which looks as though it should work provided `Data311` exists.

Third, `lm()` is not working as expected because the `Date` column is of class "factor", not class "Date". So linear regression is treating each day as a factor, hence the message `only using the first two of 365 regression coefficients`.

So: assuming that you have `PHONE`, first convert Date to "Date":

```
PHONE$Date <- as.Date(PHONE$Date, "%m/%d/%y")
```

No reason why `plot` should not work:

```
plot(PHONE$Calls, 
     type = "o", 
     col = "orange", 
     xlab = "Date", 
     ylab = "Calls", 
     main = "Time Series Analysis of 311 Calls")
```

And your `abline()` should work if `Date` is now of type date. R will convert to numeric to do the regression, but you could also do that yourself.

But now the real question: why are you using linear regression here? Do you really expect a linear relationship where calls increase or decrease with time?

Comment: Actually Date was a factor. Fortunately for your code, there is an `as.Date.factor` method.

Comment: >plot(PHONE$Calls, type = "o", col = "orange", xlab = "Date",  ylab = "Calls", main = "Time Series Analysis of 311 Calls")
> abline(lm(Calls~Date, data=PHONE), col="black")
Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet                                                         I am still getting this error unsure why. Also the regression line is only being shown to compare it with another graph and data set the has temporal autocorrelation.

Comment: Presumably you are not seeing the results of the `plot` command if you are getting that error. [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7154246/89482).