# Error in R jupyter "plot.new has not been called yet."

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, curve, normal-distribution

I am trying to run this code in R on Jupyter Notebook.

The code is to plot a curve using the output of normal distribution.

```
curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(iris$Petal.Width), sd = sd(iris$Petal.Width)), add = TRUE)
```

The value of x is:

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 50

I am getting this error

> Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...): plot.new has not
>   been called yet.

I tried looking for similar posts such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55376837/r-plot-new-has-not-been-called-yet). But the solution provided was not helpful in my case.

can anyone help me with this error or point me in the right direction? thank you.

Comment: I think this is a good question, whoever downvoted it should have given at least a short explanation why. To compensate partly I gave the question a +1. The reason is that if you set up an R plot in a Jupyter/IPython notebook cell, and then try to add something with `curve`, `abline`, etc., in _the next cell_, then you'll fail because the `plot` setup is not remembered across cells, and you end up with an error message similar to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the problem with jupyter, for curve, you need to provide the function, and also plot something before you do curve with add=TRUE. try something like this below:

```
f = function(x){
dnorm(x,mean=mean(iris$Petal.Width),sd=sd(iris$Petal.Width))
}
values = 1:10
plot(values,f(values),col="blue")
curve(f,values,add=TRUE)
```

[image]