# How to add a grid to an R plot - error int_abline .. plot.new has not bee ncalled yet

Tags: r, plot, effects, glmmtmb

I am trying to plot effects from GLMM model and I would like to add a grid along y axis from 0 to 2 every 0.2 steps and from x from 0 to 0.030 every 0.003 steps. I am familiar with this in Python but the syntax in R is still not clear to me. This is what I have so far:

```
plot(allEffects(glmm_model), xlim=c(0,0.030), ylim=c(0,2))
grid(nx=10, ny=10, lty=2, col='gray',lwd=2)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154133/plot-new-has-not-been-called-yet?rq=1